# How is tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: protocol method updating cell content in Cocoa Touch?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

So I'm using the required protocol methods from `UITableViewDataSource` to display rows on my application. It's working fine and everything but the book I'm learning from doesn't show me exactly how these rows are being updated.

In the method below there is no for loop so I'm wondering if the updating of the rows is done in a for loop in the background or something?

If not is it just updating all rows at once? So let's say in the other required method `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` I'm returning an int with the value of 5. Doe's the method below just take that info and say ok you have 5 rows I'll set the textLabel text for each of them in one go?

I'd like to get a deeper understanding of this.

**Code:**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Create an instance of UITableViewCell, with the default appearance/style and name
    // a reuseIdentify, used to identify cells with the same content
    UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"];

    // Use the index path row number to grab the BNRItem out of the allItems an
    BNRItem *p = [[[BNRItemStore sharedStore] allItems] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

    // Set text label of cell using the BNRItem stored in "P".
    [[cell textLabel] setText:[p description]];
    return cell;

}
```

Kind regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method is called by the table view whenever it feels it needs to update a cell. So, if you have five rows on screen, it will call it for those five rows (and maybe a couple of extra). Then, as you scroll, it will call it for rows that are about to appear on the screen. Cells that have scrolled off screen will be added to the reuse pool, limiting the total number of sub views that need to be created fresh and added to the table.

This is a common pattern in Cocoa; to adapt an existing control (like a table), you wouldn't subclass it, you'd configure a separate object (in this case, the datasource) which implements various methods. When the control needs to know something, it calls the relevant method on your specially configured object. It's basically the delegate pattern, except a table view already has a delegate, and the data source does a slightly different job.

By the look of your sample code you're using the Big Nerd Ranch book - their Mac OS X book had one of the best descriptions of subclassing versus delegation that I've read. Something like:

> [Robocop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RoboCop) is a subclassed human. Every part has been replaced with a custom one. [Michael Knight](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knight_Rider_%281982_TV_series%29) uses a powerful delegate object (KITT) instead.

Which do you think is the more lightweight and flexible design?

Answer (score 1):

jrturton covered the answer pretty well.

I would like to add some thoughts.

You are thinking procedurally: Write a for-loop that fills your UI with content from an array.

iOS is an event-driven OS, and Objective C is an object-oriented language. Events happen in the OS, and in response messages get sent to objets.

A table view is an autonomous object that does things on it's own. When a table view is added to the current screen's view hierarchy, it wakes up and figures out what content to display by asking the data source how many sections of data it has, and how many rows per section. It also asks how tall each cell should be. Once it has that information, it decides which items it should display, and asks the data source for cells to display.

If the user scrolls the table view it will recycle cells as they go off-screen and ask the data source to configure new cells for newly exposed data.